# How to add class to a certain element with a custom attribute?

Tags: jquery

I have a list with some LI links.

I want to add a class to this li when the link is clicked, here you are my code:

```
<ul id="sliders_buttons_list">
            <a href="#" uid="1">
                <li class="" uid="1">
                    First tab
                </li>
            </a>

            <a href="#" uid="2">
                <li class="" uid="2">
                    Second tab
                </li>
            </a>

            <a href="#" uid="3">
                <li class="" uid="3">
                    Third tab
                </li>
            </a>

        </ul>
```

If I click the link with uid = 1 I wand to add a new class to the li with uid = 1

Thanks!

Comment: Your markup is not correct, <li> must be inside <ul>.

Comment: I don't like the "uid" attributes you are using because this is not standard (X)HTML(5). Also you don't need id's on both the <a> elements and the <li> elements, the id for the <a> element is redundant. I would use the "id" attribute and only on the <li> element like this <li id="1"><a href="#">First tab</a></li>. If you don't like id, at least use a data attribute <li data-app-uid="1">...   (edited with the <li> and <a> elements reversed, following @morgar's excellent comment)

Comment: `uid` is not an existing valid attribute. Use `data-uid` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#sliders_buttons_list a').click(function(){

     $('li[uid='+$(this).attr('uid')+']').addClass('newClass');

})
```

So if you click on `a` with uid=1, the li with uid=1 will get the class 'newClass'
Same for uid=2 and so on..

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#sliders_buttons_list").delegate("a", "click", function()
{
     var uid = this.getAttribute("uid");
     $(this).find("li").addClass("uid_" + uid);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#sliders_buttons_list a[uid]").click(function(){
    var uid = $(this).attr("uid");
  $(this).find("li[uid='" + uid +"']").addClass("someClass");
});
```

**[Code example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/cjb72/1/)**